# how to uncheck the radio button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to uncheck the radio button.i tried this

```
RadioButton1.Checked = false;
```

but radio button is check. i am new to asp.net.how to do it...thanks

Comment: Some more code will help, is alone, when you call this checked=false ? maybe is the first default on page and get checked again ?

Comment: Your code line is correct. Can you show your rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

change your code as following and see if it works.

```
 this.RadioButton1.Checked = false;
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript.  It's cleaner and much more efficient.

Using jQuery:

```
$('#CheckBoxID').attr('checked', false);
```

Using regular old JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('CheckBoxID').checked = false;
```

Without understanding the scope of you issue, this is all I can say.  Perhaps you can explain the situation a little more?